# request a list to ModelViewSet and check duplicates before insert

Tags: django-rest-framework

A bit confused of usage of `ModelViewSet`. I am building a meeting room reservation system. And for reservation I am inserting **reservation times** to DB. But before insert I need to check room already reserved at selected time.

So user selects **start** and **finish** times and sends a request. let's say user selects between 09:00 and 14:00

```
let requestForm = []

this.times.some(time => {
  if (time >= this.form.meeting_time_start && time <= this.form.meeting_time_finish) {
    this.form.meeting_time = time
    requestForm.push(this.form)
  }
})

this.$store.dispatch("MEETING_ROOM_CONTENT_INSERT_OR_UPDATE", requestForm)
```

this means `requestForm` now is an Array of Objects. And each object holding a value of time **09:00, 10:00, 11:00 ~ till 14:00**

But on backend side ModelViewSet always wait an validated_data as an object(dict).

```
class MeetingRoomContentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
  queryset = MeetingRoomContent.objects.all()
  serializer_class = MeetingRoomContentSerializer
  permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

  def perform_create(self, serializer):
    serializer.save()
    return serializer
```

Of course I can send objects one by one but that's not a proper way for my situation. I want to send times as a list and check if any of time has already reserved or not. Is it possible for ModelViewSet to take array(LIST) and loop it before insert.

Additionally, if you need to see `Serializer.py` Here:

```
class MeetingRoomContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = MeetingRoomContent
    fields = "__all__"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at DRF [ListSerializer](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#listserializer).

ModelViewSet only allow you to create one object per request. In order to perform batch create, you will need a custom view that accept, validate & perform create list of objects.

For example by using DRF [action](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing) decorator:

```
class MeetingRoomContentViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = MeetingRoomContent.objects.all()
    serializer_class = MeetingRoomContentSerializer
    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]

    @action(detail=False, methods=['post'])
    def batch_create(self, request):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, many=True)
        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
        serializer.save()
        return Response(serializer.data, status=201)
```

Your serializer classes:

```
class MeetingRoomContentListSerializer(serializers.ListSerializer):
    def validate(self, data):
        validated_data = super().validate(data)
        # validated_data will be list of objects
        # perform checking duplications
        return validated_data
 

class MeetingRoomContentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = MeetingRoomContent
        fields = "__all__"
        list_serializer_class = MeetingRoomContentListSerializer
```